# Chased by a lion and other pursuit-evasion problems

Tags: reference-request, differential-games

I am looking for a reference (book or article) that poses a problem that seems to be a classic, in that I've heard it posed many times, but that I've never seen written anywhere: that of the possibility of a man in a circular pen with a lion, each with some maximum speed, avoiding capture by that lion.

References to pursuit problems in general would also be appreciated, and the original source of this problem.

Comment: e.g., http://xkcd.com/135/ ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since you're asking for a reference, perhaps this will do?

Wolfram Mathworld says the problem was listed by Rado in 1925. The reference is on the problem description page, [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LionandManProblem.html).

Answer (score 6):

Here is a book on this type of problem

- Paul J. Nahin, [Chases and escapes: the mathematics of pursuit and evasion](http://books.google.com/books?id=HeESjfM2geUC), Princeton University Press, 2007.

it is also briefly mentioned in his other book "Euler's Fabulous Formula".

Comment: The book is *Chases and escapes: the mathematics of pursuit and evasion* by Paul J. Nahin. [Google Books Preview](http://books.google.com/books?id=HeESjfM2geUC&printsec=frontcover)

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo Done

Answer (score 5):

The book is Coffee in Memphis by Bollobas. It's the first problem, and there are loads more :

[http://www.amazon.com/Art-Mathematics-Coffee-Time-Memphis/dp/0521693950](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521693950)

Comment: http://arxiv.org/abs/0909.2524