# Lion and Rabbit in a Cage — references

Tags: optimization, reference-request, optimal-control, differential-games

I am looking for references to a problem with the following approximate statement:

> There is a lion and a rabbit in cage $C$. At the initial time they are at locations $I_l$ and $I_r$, they have maximum speed of $S_l$ and $S_r$, respectively. The lion wants to reach the rabbit at the shortest time. The rabbit wants to escape from the lion for the longest time. Find an optimal strategy and optimal time for each.

---

As far as I remember there were no statements about restrictions on acceleration or path. But any variant is of interest.

Comment: You’d also want the size of the cage, and reaction time for each animal.

Comment: Lawrence C. Evans, [An Introduction to Mathematical Optimal Control Theory](https://math.berkeley.edu/%7Eevans/control.course.pdf) [PDF], Department of Mathematics, University of California, Berkeley.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/31097 and https://math.stackexchange.com/q/98 and https://math.stackexchange.com/q/96595

Comment: Related: https://arxiv.org/abs/0909.2524

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QM9Bynjh2Lk

Comment: @WillJagy OK, in the interest of equal opportunity you may edit the question to have the rabbit hunt the lion. As it is written "I saw something else under the sun..."

Comment: Maesumi, one thing i thought was a myth turned out to be real; I guess in desert areas, an eagle will pick up a tortoise, fly up fairly high, drop it on a hard area; then it can separate the shell and eat the tortoise. This is given as the way Aeschylus died, ancient Greek playwright. My source for the non-myth part is a youtube video from a nature show.